# ConfigParser and Scrapy: NoSectionError

Tags: python, configparser

I have a issue with my Scrapy crawler when I launch it.

I used ConfigParser in order to have a small config.ini to set my table name which i create each time i launch the crawler to scrap. That a basic way to scrap but i'm still noob with scrapy and python

I get the folowings errors:

```
File "c:\python27\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 279, in options
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'SectionOne'
2016-02-04 15:10:57 [twisted] CRITICAL:
```

Here is my config.py:

```
import ConfigParser 
import os

Config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
Config.read(os.getcwd() + '/config.ini')

def ConfigSectionMap(section):
    dict1 = {}
    options = Config.options(section)
    for option in options:
        try:
           dict1[option] = Config.get(section, option)
           if dict1[option] == -1:
               DebugPrint("skip: %s" % option)
        except:
            print("exception on %s!" % option)
            dict1[option] = None
    return dict1
```

Here is my config.ini

```
[SectionOne]
nom_table: Seche_cheveux
```

Here is my pipeline.py:

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import date, datetime
import os
from config import *

TableName = ConfigSectionMap("SectionOne")['nom_table']
print TableName


class  sqlite3Pipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        #initialisation de la base et connexion
        try:
            #self.setupDBCon()
            self.con = sqlite3.connect(os.getcwd() + '/db.sqlite')
            self.cur = self.con.cursor()
            self.table_name = TableName
            self.createTables()
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            raise e


    def createTables(self):
        self.createMgTable()

    def closeDB(self):
        self.con.close()

    def __del__(self):
        self.closeDB()

    def createMgTable(self, table_name):
        self.cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + table_name + "(\
        nom TEXT UNIQUE, \
        url TEXT UNIQUE, \
        prix TEXT, \
        stock TEXT, \
        revendeur TEXT, \
        livraison TEXT, \
        img TEXT UNIQUE, \
        detail TEXT UNIQUE, \
        bullet TEXT UNIQUE, \
        created_at DATE \
        )")

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.storeInDb(item)
        return item

    def storeInDb(self,item):
       etc....
       etc...
```

Please can you tell me how i can handle configparser with scrapy crawler ? and if possible tell me what i'm doing wrong

For info when i start each file seperatly ,all print function i included works welll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConfigParser.read()` tends to fail silently when the config file is not found. There's probably a change in the current working directory (`os.getcwd()`) that prevents it from finding `config.ini`.

If your `config.ini` file is next to your `config.py`, you can use this instead:

```
Config.read(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'config.ini'))
```